# Can the line at infinity be considered a circle?

Tags: geometry

I was just reading a short story about "a circle with no circumference and many centers."   I thought it was a kind of a koan.  But then the math lessons start to come back to me.  I remember in one class, we were asked to imagine lines as a circle with their center at the line at infinity.  I wonder if the line at infinity, being that it is also a "line," could also be considered as a circle in the same way.

Comment: Well for the Euclidean $n$-space, its Tits boundary is the $n-1$-sphere...

Comment: That's interesting.  I'll try to read up on that topic although I'll be out of my depth, probably.  (I had the idea of trying to look for videos explaining "Tits boundary."   Bad idea..)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Briefly, there are multiple useful ways to add "points at infinity" to the Euclidean plane, there is an extension of meaning in viewing a line in the Euclidean plane as a "circle centered at infinity", and there is a further extension of meaning in asking whether "the line at infinity is a circle". Depending how we make sense of these issues, the answer to the question could reasonably be either _yes_ or _no_.

Comment: While Andrew D. Hwang is correct that it is a matter of how you wish to define the related issues, from a naive point of view: note that in any direction, there is a "point" at infinity in that direction. Thus as you continuously change the direction, the point at infinity changes, continuously traversing the line at infinity, and eventually you will come around again to the original direction, and your original point. The "line at infinity" is closed. As you move along it, you will come back to where you started. This is the behavior of a circle, not a line.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I'm not happy with that answer. Is there any specific property of circles that makes it reasonable to consider lines as circles with *centre* at infinity? I'm not sure this is possible in the real projective plane, since conics seem to be indistinguishable when it is viewed as part of the real projective space, and conics don't have 'centres'. On the other hand, I distinctly recall that there were a number of geometry theorems that were much more elegant when allowing lines to be circles centred at infinity, but that was too long ago so my memory is fuzzy now.

Comment: @user21820 - first, my comment was about the "line at infinity", and merely notes that it is a closed curve. It was not about lines being circles with centers at infinity. For that idea, take a line, and consider a perpendicular. For some point on perpendicular, draw the circle with point as center and tangent to the line. As you move the center farther out, the circle approaches the line. It can be said to converge to the line in the limit (for an appropriate definition of that limit). The point at infinity approached is the same for all perpendiculars, so it can be considered the center.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I know about that limiting process. Similarly we can consider the Apollonian pencils to include lines with the appropriate centres at infinity, But it does not seem satisfactory, because distances and angles don't really exist in the real projective plane, so what does it really mean to claim that the limit is that particular point at infinity in the real projective plane?

Comment: @user21820 - have you lost sight of where the projective plane comes from? It is just the ordinary Euclidean plane with the points at infinity added. Distance and angles exist in the Euclidean plane, and they exist in the projective plane as well. But certain concepts about them we use instinctively in the Euclidean plane break down, so they have to be approached with more care. But this doesn't mean that they disappear altogether. The Euclidean plane with all of it properties still sits within the projective plane.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I haven't lost sight of anything; why so aggressive? I said it is not satisfactory to just arbitrarily add points without a clear structure, **if** you want to extend the notion of "circle" to possibly include points at infinity. Taking limits is not satisfactory unless there is some guarantee that it always 'works'. And it still doesn't address the question of why the line at infinity ought to be a circle and not an ellipse.

Comment: @user21820  Wouldn't it have the symmetry of a circle and not the ellipse?

Comment: @AndrewLim: But **what** do you mean by symmetry? That is the whole point I made here. If you do not have a precise definition of "circle" or "symmetry" or something that can unambiguously distinguish between circles and conics in a meaningful way in the real projective plane (not just saying let's call it a circle because we want to), you simply don't have a meaningful way to consider the line at infinity a circle and not a conic. It's a standard fact that conics are more or less indistinguishable in the real projective plane in the sense that projective mappings preserve but do not fix them.

Comment: (My last sentence was of course when the real projective plane is embedded in the real projective space.) By the way, I'm not saying your question is not an interesting one. But you really need to consider that if you want lines to have centre at infinity and the line at infinity to be a circle, you need to define "circle" and "centre" in a sufficiently elegant way that *agrees with* the standard definition for finite circles and their centres. There must be some compelling uniform description of general circles, otherwise it is just a name.

Comment: @user21820 That's really fascinating.  I think I have to study more.  Thank you for indulging my question.  Incidentally, I tried to google the phrase  "a circle with no circumference and many centers" and a result is returned for 'an infinite sphere, whose centre is everywhere and whose circumference is nowhere' which is attributed to Blaise Pascal.  I think Pascal also studied projective geometry.  I wonder if that was what he was talking about.

Comment: @AndrewLim: If you want I can post a partial answer about the real projective plane. I didn't post earlier because I don't see a nice way of incorporating circle centres.